# How to uncheck a checkbox using Javascript(closure)?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, google-closure

I have following code in my javascript code

> goog.dom.$(changeIdStr).getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked = false
> console.log(typeof(goog.dom.$(changeIdStr).getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked)
> console.log(goog.dom.$(changeIdStr).getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked);
> console.log(goog.dom.$(changeIdStr).innerHTML);

and the corresponding log is

> boolean
>
> false

```
<label><input type="checkbox"
onclick="handleSelectedUrl('selected_1_0', 'selected_', 'url_')"
name="selected[]" value="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948356/"
checked=""><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948356/"
target="_blank">http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2948356/</a></label>
```

So why the checked attribute is false, there is still checked="" in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be `checked="true"` instead of `checked=""` to return true.

Comment: So I did goog.dom.$(changeIdStr).getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked=false; before all the logging. Do you know why it does't uncheck the box?

Comment: that may be an issue with the closure library, try `.removeAttribute('checked')` to uncheck

Answer (score 0):

For a checkbox, by default if it is false then there is no checked attribute added in the html.

But after that if you make it true or checked then attribute gets added and set to "checked". If you make it unchecked or false, it becomes empty but the checkbox attribute doesn't get removed. This is equivalent to checkbox false.